# Error Minimization using Gradient Descent without training data

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, gradient-descent

I have two vectors, V1 is ideal and V2 is the real data. Each one of these vectors is multiplied (dot product) by a vector A.
V1-dot-A = S1 (scalar) and V2-dot-A = S2.  Now what I want is to determine which item(s) in V2 contribute most to the error S1-S2.
How can I take advantage of error minimization using gradient descent to solve this problem given there is no training data?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas
import tensorflow as tf

@tf.function
def cost(V, A,S1):
    S = tf.tensordot(V,A,1)
    error = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(S - S1))
    return error

A  = [float(x) for x in '7  244 39  0   0   0   0   0   47  107 0   0   0   0   152 0   0   98  0   17  0   81  0   0   0   0   25  124 0   0   0   0   0   202 0   64  141 0   0   94  19  1   0   0   28  0   177 47  56  0   0   123 138 107 254 70  0   86  0   0   0   99  179 12'.split()]
V1 = [float(x) for x in '1  2   -1  -2  3   -2  -2  -1  2   2   0   -6  0   -3  2   2   -3  4   -2  -1  -7  1   -3  2   -2  -2  2   -2  2   -4  0   -3  -3  -2  -1  1   -1  -1  -3  2   1   -1  2   -1  0   2   3   -1  1   1   -1  2   1   0   -1  0   -3  1   -1  1   1   0   2   1'.split()]
V2 = [float(x) for x in '0.8    1.4 -0.8    -1.6    2.4 -1.8    -1.4    -0.8    1.4 1.6 0   -5.4    0   -2.4    1.6 1.4 -2.2    2.8 -1.6    -0.8    -5.4    0.8 -2  1.4 -1.6    -1.6    1.4 -1.8    1.6 -3.2    0   -2.6    -2.4    -1.8    -0.8    0.8 -0.8    -0.8    -2.6    1.6 0.8 -1  1.4 -0.8    0   1.4 2.6 -0.8    0.8 0.8 -0.8    1.4 0.8 0   -0.8    0   -2.4    0.8 -0.8    0.8 0.8 0   1.4 0.8'.split()]

A = np.asarray(A)
V1 = np.asarray(V1)
V2 = np.asarray(V2)
S1 = V1.dot(A))


optimizer = tf.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.01)
trainable_vars = [V2]

epochs = 100 #(or however many iterations you want it to run)
for _ in range(epochs):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tp:
        cost_fn = cost(V2, A, S1)
    gradients = tp.gradient(cost_fn, trainable_vars)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, trainable_vars))

tf.print(V2)
```